# once defined ,string cannot be initialized to other characters?

Tags: c

Using pointers string can be initialized to other characters but when once string has been defined it cannot be initialized to other characters.What is the reason behind it??

```
int main()
{
char str1[]="hello";
char *p="hello";
str1="bye";/*error*/
p="bye";/*works*/
}
```

Comment: Nick: In this case, the * (in "char *p") means that p is a pointer variable. That is, the variable p doesn't contain a character, but the address to a place in memory where there is a character.

Comment: pl. also see some useful links http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html

Comment: A more pertinent duplicate would discuss the use of `strcpy()` et al for assigning to strings.  The proposed duplicate does not do that.  Other questions might be more appropriate.  A casual search found: [Why is `strcpy()` necessary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901090/) and [Why does a char array need `strcpy` and `char *` doesn't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508233/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are arrays and pointers are pointers. Defining arrays gives the pointer to the allocated array, that is a constant pointer to the location where the array space hass been reserved. That is a concrete address in the lifo stack. So, str1 is a constant pointer value and you cannot change it. You cannot set the value of the address of a different constant string.

Defining pointers, as char*p,  gives you a variable value of an address. And so, you can change de value of the variable p.

Answer (score 1):

You've defined `str1` as an array, and arrays aren't assignable.

You can, however, copy other data into the array, for example:

```
char str1[] = "hello";

strcpy(str1, "bye");
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the characters in an array such as what you are doing you have to use a function such as `strcpy` or do it index by index.

```
str1[0] = 'p';
```

will print out `pello`

What you are trying to do is not supported by the C language.