# Add char in struct

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, struct

Why can't I add `name` into the `data` function?

If I run this code

```
data->userName = name;
```

that line is an error. Why can't I set `userName` to `name`?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
typedef struct User {
    char userName[5];
    int  userAge;
} User;
int roomNum = 0;
void data (User* data, int age, char* name);

main () {
    int age;
    char name[5];
    User list[10] = {};
    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++) {
        scanf("%d",&age);
        scanf("%s",name);

        data(&list[roomNum],age,name);
        roomNum ++;
    }

    NSLog(@"%d   %s",list[0].userAge,list [0].userName);
    NSLog(@"%d   %s",list[1].userAge,list[1].userName);
    NSLog(@"%d   %s",list[2].userAge,list[2].userName);
}

void data (User* data, int age, char* name){
    NSLog(@"%s",name);
    (*data).userAge = age;
    data->userName = name;
}
```

Comment: Use `strcpy` to copy strings.

Comment: strcpy is the only way to solve the problem?

Comment: Other ways are `sprintf()` and `strncpy()` and `memcpy()` but `strcpy()` is usual.

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901090/c-why-is-strcpy-necessary) link. As is explained in AndreyT's answer, arrays in C are non-assignable (with only a few notable exceptions).

Comment: Use `strcpy()`, or preferably `strncpy()` or even better, `strlcpy()` to copy data between strings. You are attempting to do a shallow copy via the assignment operator, which is not going to generate the results you want. Also, considering using a macro to determine maximum buffer sizes (ie: `#define BUF_SIZE 255   ....  char name[BUF_SIZE]`, unless you plan to dynamically allocate memory for strings with `calloc`, `malloc`, or `strdup`.

Comment: oh thank you for answering my question. but is there any way to solve this problem without using function?

Comment: Of course - roll your own. But the libraries are there for a good reason

Comment: Best course of action: Get a "C" programming language book and take some time to sturdy the language.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend one correction, instead of this

```
scanf("%s",name);
```

try with this

```
scanf("%4s",name);
  /*    ^ should be sizeof(name) - 1 */
```

so you prevent overflowing `name`, and to store the value in the struct instead of

```
data->userName = name;
```

use

```
strcpy(data->userName, name);
```

also, why are you doing this

```
(*data).userAge = age;
```

use consistent syntax either stick to the previous line, or

```
data->userAge = age;
```